# .apply() method doesn't work with jQuery .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've created an object literal of jQuery animations and I'm looking for a succinct way of passing this to `animate()`.

Unfortunately, `.apply()` doesn't seem to work with `animate()` so I've had to resort to using the indexes - I'm wondering why this is and how I can get it to work with `.apply()`.

```
var animations = {

    slideLeft : function (moveLeft) {

        return [{
                left: moveLeft
            }, {
                duration: 300,
                easing: 'swingy'
        }];

    }
};

$randomEl.animate.apply(this, animations.slideLeft(100)); // doesn't work

$randomEl.animate(animations.slideLeft(100)[0], animations.slideLeft(100)[1]); // does work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the right value for `this` to `apply`. I assume this works:

```
$randomEl.animate.apply($randomEl, animations.slideLeft(100));
```

If you call `animate` normally, like `$randomEl.animate(...)`, then inside `animate`, `this` will refer to `$randomEl`. Hence you have to pass `$randomEl` as first argument to `apply` and not whatever `this` refers to.

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You supply the wrong `this` parameter to the animate function. You should pass `$randomEl` instead of `this`.